# elementary OS and Opera Browser

Tags: opera

Hey does anyone know how to permanently make opera work by doing some setting or something without launching in the terminal?.  I want to go back from vivaldi for a while.  Here is a link for an elementary OS only hack to make the main menu work.  (thanks to google.. I have no idea how they do this).

https://forums.opera.com/topic/23229/o-menu-missing-for-elementaryos-loki

Key point is this:  Hi guys, @robbooker, @minuteman, you can try to run the Opera with the switch as follows/usr/bin/opera --show-opera-menu.
If it doesn't work, you can also try XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME /usr/bin/opera.

Answer (score 1):

Opera is working fine

I just used snap to install it and here you can see the main window

https://snapcraft.io/opera

[image: Opera browser main dark window]

Now if I disable the sidebar in settings

[image: Opera browser main dark window, sidebar disabled]

---

This is the APT version of Opera, same images

[image: Opera browser main light window]

[image: Opera browser main light window, sidebar disabled]

To install it through APT just:

```
$ wget -qO- https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free'
$ sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```

https://deb.opera.com/manual.html

(current add-apt-repository run and update after you add a repo, so you need to add the key first)

---

Maybe your problem is that you have residual settings in your /home?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the launcher so that it runs Opera automatically with the additional options. I tested by adding a third launch action. Now, I can right-click the Opera icon and select *New Window with "O"*. You could also make this the default behavior. Here's how I did it.

In Terminal, I edited the desktop info for Opera.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/opera.desktop
```

I appended `;NewWindowWithO` to `Actions=NewWindow;NewPrivateWindow` and then defined the action by adding the following to the bottom of the file:

```
[Desktop Action NewWindowWithO]
Name=New Window with "O"
Exec=opera --show-opera-menu --new-window
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Save the changes. You should now be able to right-click the Opera icon in dock and select the new action.

If you want the default action (left-click) to open with the "O" menu, then you can add `--show-opera-menu` to the `Exec` and `TryExec` fields in the `[Desktop Entry]` section.

I'm not sure if this file will be overwritten if you install a newer version of Opera, so you may want to delete or revert it to it's original before you update.

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed it?

I'm using Opera (it's my favorite browser for years) and I installed trhough the official .deb file provided by their website. It even asks you to allow regular updates with the rest of the system and it works.

I've never needed to run it by the terminal, it creates the shortcuts by itself flawlessly. Maybe your problem has to do with the method or origin by which you had it installed.